# Add a checkbox on top of a clickable div

Tags: jquery, html

How do I add a checkbox on top of a clickable element, that won't send the click event to the clickable element?
(To generalize the question - add a non-clickable element on top of a clickable element)

Example here:
http://jsbin.com/uyecaq/4/edit

Thanks!

To Clarify - When the checkbox is clicked, the div that it sits in should not receive the click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this..

```
$('.checkboxpart').click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This one will bind a click on checkbox, overriding default action. The click on the div occurs due to Event propagation. So we need to stop that.

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 4):

Try adding:

```
$('.checkboxpart').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the checkbox is clicked first

```
$(".clickme").click(function(e) {
    if($('#checkboxid').is(':checked')) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```